# CodeIgniter: Not able to hit controller specific method

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to Codeigniter. While trying to access controller specific method, I am getting '`Object Not found`' exception.

Before hitting the url I did following changes:

- base_url set as `http://localhost/test/` in config.php
- default_controller set as `main`
- Defined index and login method in main.php class

If I try to hit just `http://localhost/test/`, it returns echo from the index method. But if I directly give `http://localhost/test/main/login` then it throws `Object not found` exception. 
Strangely if I give `$this->login();` into index method of main controller class, `http://localhost/test/`hits the login method. I have tried to change login method to `public` but no luck.
What I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be the common `index.php` problem

This should do it: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

But please confirm it by trying to access the controller with a `index.php` in behind it like so:

```
http://localhost/test/index.php/main/login
```